# How can one display multiple data from mongodb to JTextArea in netbeans

Tags: java, mongodb

I have been trying to get all the data in a collection to display on a JTextArea in netbeans but only one document is shown
Need some help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We've a guide [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It would be great if you add some more details like the code you're using already, then it's easier to help and you can expect faster an answer. Thank's!

Comment: Hi, please add some code-snippets or some more detailed information to your question, so that others are able to help you.

Comment: Going from data storage to displaying contains a lot of steps. I suggest you read up on the topics at hand and split up your requirement into multiple steps/questions and work on them 1 by 1.